# Adding authentication in api endpoint - ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net, api, asp.net-core, backend

I started code own site with backend ASP.NET Core and React. I get a basic code to create an ASP backend with authentication from this 
https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/10/14/aspnet-core-3-simple-api-for-authentication-registration-and-user-management#running-react

I created an endpoint to my API which allows adding a photo to my server and It's working

```
 [HttpPost("{username}/photos/")]
        public IActionResult AddPhoto(String username, [FromForm]IFormFile photo)
        {

            //add img to static folder
            var wwww_root = _webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath;
            var path = @"\profiles\" + username + @"\profile_photos\";
            var upload_path = wwww_root + path;

            var pathForFile = upload_path + photo.FileName;

            try
            {
                using (FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(pathForFile))
                {
                    photo.CopyTo(fileStream);
                    fileStream.Flush();
                }
            }
            catch(DirectoryNotFoundException e)
            {
                return NotFound("This username does not exists");
            }
            var pathOnServer = "http://" + Request.Host.Value + path + photo.FileName;
            var photoImage = _profileService.AddPhoto(username, pathOnServer);

            return Ok();

        }
```

but I want to also add authentication to use this endpoint based on the given "username" 
i.e. this endpoint returns OK when the Bearer Token is the same as that assigned to the username.

In the given link I found a method configuring the authentication:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // use sql server db in production and sqlite db in development
            if (_env.IsProduction())
                services.AddDbContext<DataContext>();
            else
                services.AddDbContext<DataContext, SqliteDataContext>();

            services.AddCors();
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

            // configure strongly typed settings objects
            var appSettingsSection = _configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
            services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection);

            // configure jwt authentication
            var appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<AppSettings>();
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.Secret);
            services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnTokenValidated = context =>
                    {
                        var userService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IUserService>();
                        var userId = int.Parse(context.Principal.Identity.Name);
                        var user = userService.GetById(userId);
                        if (user == null)
                        {
                            // return unauthorized if user no longer exists
                            context.Fail("Unauthorized");
                        }
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            });
```

And api endpoint to Authenticate:

```
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost("authenticate")]
        public IActionResult Authenticate([FromBody]AuthenticateModel model)
        {
            var user = _userService.Authenticate(model.Username, model.Password);

            if (user == null)
                return BadRequest(new { message = "Username or password is incorrect" });

            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_appSettings.Secret);
            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Id.ToString())
                }),
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
            };
            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
            var tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

            // return basic user info and authentication token
            return Ok(new
            {
                Id = user.Id,
                Username = user.Username,
                FirstName = user.FirstName,
                LastName = user.LastName,
                Token = tokenString
            });
        }
```

but I can't translate this into a solution to my problem.
I am asking for tips on how I can do it

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 1**
You can check the claims and token in your upload method
In ConfigureService add this

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

In the upload method use this:

```
// works if the token is in the header
var tokenFromHeader = HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
// or try this if .Net Core is < 3.0
var tokenFromAuth = await HttpContext.Authentication.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

// Get Claims
var identity = HttpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;

// Get user id from claims.
var userIdClaim = identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Name);

// Use the value.
if (userIdClaim != null && userIdClaim.value != null) {
   // your logic here
}
```

---

To check the authorization on api call set the attribute [Authorize] on your controller or on your method.

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost("{username}/photos/")]
public IActionResult AddPhoto(String username, [FromForm]IFormFile photo)
```

More info here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

The basic code:
Startup.cs -> ConfigureServices

```
            // configure jwt authentication
            var jwtSettings = jwtSettingsSection.Get<JwtSettings>();
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jwtSettings.JwtKey);
            services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {

                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),

                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = jwtSettings.JwtIssuer,

                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidAudience = jwtSettings.JwtAudience,

                    //RequireExpirationTime = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                };
            });
```

Startup.cs -> Configure

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Authentication Controller

```
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost()]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AuthenticateUser([FromBody] UserAuthentication userResource)
        {
            //Your logic of authorization here
            //if not authorized
            //return Unauthorized();

            var tokenString = CreateJwtToken(user);

            // return basic user info (without password) and token to store client side
            return Ok(new
            {
                Token = tokenString
            });
        }
```

Create JWT Token

```
public string CreateJwtToken(McUsers user)
{
    var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jwtSettings.JwtKey);
    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
    {
        Issuer = jwtSettings.JwtIssuer,
        Audience = jwtSettings.JwtAudience,
        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
       {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.FirstName),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, user.LastName),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.UserRole.Description)
       }),
        NotBefore = DateTime.UtcNow,
        Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(120),
        SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature)
    };

    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
    var tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

    return tokenString;
}
```

Your method in the controller

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost("{username}/photos/")]
    public IActionResult AddPhoto(String username, [FromForm]IFormFile photo)
    {

        //add img to static folder
        var wwww_root = _webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath;
        var path = @"\profiles\" + username + @"\profile_photos\";
        var upload_path = wwww_root + path;

        var pathForFile = upload_path + photo.FileName;

        try
        {
            using (FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(pathForFile))
            {
                photo.CopyTo(fileStream);
                fileStream.Flush();
            }
        }
        catch(DirectoryNotFoundException e)
        {
            return NotFound("This username does not exists");
        }
        var pathOnServer = "http://" + Request.Host.Value + path + photo.FileName;
        var photoImage = _profileService.AddPhoto(username, pathOnServer);

        return Ok();

    }
```

Comment: Maybe I do something wrong but it still does not work. I added [Authorize] and the bearer token is required but if I typed token another user the result returned OK :(

Comment: Maybe I had missed the problem, check if the edit helps you solve it